# Scalability versus portability on clouds (Amazon/GAE/...)

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, cloud, scalability, portability

I have some website written in PHP (currently on VPS) which will be rebuilt from scratch to Python.
As platform, I am mainly considering **GAE** and **Amazon** (or stay wit current **VPS**). *I would like to ask you which suits me better.*

Some of my converns:

- I know GAE has some limitations however since I am gonna build everything from scratch it might be not a huge problem (or might be?).
- I read that Amazon gives only virtual machines, so I will have to administrate everything. How does it look with scalability (I will just have to move the slider or do work with server configuration / programming?)
- What if I decide to stay with my current VPS and later migrate to Amazon? Is it gonna be painful and involve a lot of work?
- What about costs?

The website was written by me long time ago (1milion uniq users a month), now it needs to be rebuild because of mess in the code.
Now it is hosted on small VPS with 2x2GHz + 750MB RAM (20$ a month). This is more than enough, however after rebuild I plan to add more performance consuming features, also advertise it (so the website will grow).
I've chosen Python (dJango) as a framework.

Since it's gonna be completely rebuild, I am thinking about hosting it on clouds.

Answer (score 3):

Google App Engine is an example of [PaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service).  Amazon Web Services is primarily an [IaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_a_service#Service_models) solution (with some PaaS-like components).  They're different service models, each with various pluses and minuses.  Briefly: PaaS offers more abstraction of the underlying systems.  This makes deployment easier (sometimes much easier) and eliminates much of the systems engineering expertise needed to design a scalable and durable environment.  However, this comes at the cost of greatly reduced flexibility, is generally more expensive per month, and has a greater degree of "[vendor lock-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in)".

You may be interested in Amazon's [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) product, which is sort of a hybrid of PaaS and IaaS.  It's a layer on-top of several AWS components (EC2, RDS, ELB, SNS) that stich them together into an easier-to-use PaaS-like manner. *(Disclaimer: My company is a member of AWS's Consulting Partner Network and we wrote Elastic Beanstalk support for Boto, the Python AWS library.)*

> What if I decide to stay with my current VPS and later migrate to Amazon? Is it gonna be painful and involve a lot of work?

That is very much dependent on your application.  In short, you want to make sure that your application servers (instances) are treated like they're disposable: do not store persistent data on them, nor have interdependences.  For example, if your application accepts user-uploaded files, they ought to be stored in S3, not on the local volume.  You want to make sure that you're using loosely-coupled components and communicate between them using SNS and SQS.

The biggest change though is in how you roll code.  You can't just SSH or FTP into a single server and upload the latest revision.  Elastic Beanstalk integrates nicely with Git (see the docs) to make this pretty painless, but it's still an adjustment to your workflow.  If you outgrow Elastic Beanstalk, then you need to start looking at provisioning tools like Puppet, Chef, or Salt.  I've also used Fabric for simpler environments.